# Why does geom_freqpoly starts adding lines from ZERO even though there is no data in it?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am using ggplot2 to produce a frequency plot. The X-axis of my data is `AGE` and it starts from 18 and ends at 44. However, when I produce frequency plot of `AGE`, the graphs looks like this:[image]

I want those lines to start at 18 and end at 44. How is that possible?

The code is:

```
ggplot(matched.frame, aes(x=AGE, fill=as.factor(DRUG_KEY), color=as.factor(DRUG_KEY))) + 
  stat_bin(aes(ymax=..count..,), alpha=.5, ymin=0, geom="ribbon", binwidth =5, position="identity", pad=T) + 
  geom_freqpoly(binwidth=5, size=2) + 
  scale_fill_discrete(labels = c("26"="foo", "27"="bar"), name = "Labels") + 
  scale_color_discrete(labels = c("26"="foo", "27"="bar"), name = "Labels") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(18, 44, 2)) +
  xlab("AGE") + ylab("Number of Patients") +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold", size=12)) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold", size=12)) +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold", size=14)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(face="bold", size=14))
```